# How to execute simply list of shell commands with pipe using Groovy?

Tags: shell, groovy

Already we know that,

```
def total_cmd = ("less test.txt").execute() | ("wc -l").execute()
total_cmd.waitFor()
println total_cmd.getText()
```

How can i do this from a list of `n` commands like,

```
def cmd_list = [ "cmd1".execute(), "cmd2".execute(),....,"cmdn".execute()]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute, then reduce:

```
total_cmd = cmd_list*.execute().inject{a,b -> a | b}
```

This assumes `a|b == b|a`